# What is the mistake in my code for the problem "Find Median from Data Stream"?

Tags: c++, algorithm, sorting, data-structures, priority-queue

I'm been struggling to solve the question [Find Median from Data Stream](https://leetcode.com/problems/find-median-from-data-stream/) on LeetCode for the last 2 hours but couldn't find the mistake in my code.

My algorithm is to put two priority queues, the first one is a max-priority queue which stores the elements less than the median, and the second one is a min-priority queue which stores the elements greater than the median.

This is my code:

```
struct get_min{
    bool operator()(int i, int j){
        return i>j;
    }
};
class MedianFinder {
    //queue which stores elements which are greater than the median
    priority_queue<int, vector<int>, get_min> max;
    int minSize, maxSize;
    //queue which stores elements which are less than the median
    priority_queue<int> min;
public:
    MedianFinder() {
        minSize = 0;
        maxSize = 0;
    }
    
    void addNum(int num) {
        if(minSize>maxSize){
            int x = min.top();
            if(x<num){
                max.push(num);
            }else{
                min.push(num);
                max.push(min.top());
                min.pop();
            }
            maxSize++;
        }else if(minSize < maxSize){
            int x = max.top();
            if(x>num)min.push(x);
            else{
                max.push(num);
                min.push(max.top());
                max.pop();
            }
            minSize++;
        }else if(minSize==0 && maxSize==0){
            min.push(num);
            minSize++;
        }else{
            int x = min.top();
            int y = max.top();
            if(num<=x){
                min.push(num);
                minSize++;
            }else{
                max.push(num);
                maxSize++;
            }
        }
    }
    
    double findMedian() {
        if(minSize> maxSize)return min.top();
        else if(minSize<maxSize)return max.top();
        else return (double(min.top()+max.top())/2);
    }
};
```

For the input where the following numbers are given one by one and the median of those numbers should be output after taking each number as input, I'm getting the incorrect output.

Stream of numbers:

```
6, 10, 2, 6, 5,  0, 6,  3, 1,  0, 0
```

My output:

```
6, 8,  6, 6, 6,5.5, 6,  6, 6,5.5, 5
```

Expected Output:

```
6, 8,  6, 6, 6,5.5, 6,5.5, 5,  4, 3
```

Comment: Since you have a test case that's failing the best way to work this out is by using the debugger and stepping through the code to see where it goes wrong.

Comment: @paddy, as this is an algo question, I want to get the optimized solution. That vector thing has more time complexity.

Comment: @KenY-N, You can't do it in O(N). We have a stream of integers coming and we have to be able to give median at any point in time. Maintaining two priority queues is the best solution. (Please read the question properly.)

Comment: PS;[`std::greater`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/greater) is probably better than `get_min`.

Comment: Are you sure that `if(x>num)min.push(x);` is right?  Why would you put a value in the max queue into the min queue and ignore the num altogether?  It should be `if(x<num) max.push(num);` right?

Comment: @JerryJeremiah, yes, thanks, I have to put  `num` not `x`. Thank you soo much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As [Jerry Jeremiah](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2193968/jerry-jeremiah) commented the issue with the code,

in the line, `if(x>num)min.push(x);` you are completely ignoring the `num` and pushing `x` into the queue. You have to change that and your code will  get accepted.